# Conditionally execute javascript if MVC Model is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to execute an ajax POST when a bootstrap panel heading is clicked. This post is populating my view model. I would only like this event to occur when `Model.OrdersInEvaluation` is null so it will not do a post every time the heading is clicked. So, I am trying to combine razor and javascript:

```
<script>
@if (Model.OrdersInEvaluation == null)
{
    <Text>
    $("#evaluation-panel-heading").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EvaluationOrders", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#evaluation-panel-body").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</Text>
}
</script>
```

I know that `Model.OrdersInEvaluation` is populating because the table in my view is being populated with it on the ajax call. Am I using `<text>` incorrectly? Or is there maybe another error in the code that would cause this to execute every time it is clicked?

Comment: It would probably be easier to add a `data-` attribute to your element indicating if the value if null (say `data-exists="@Model.OrdersInEvaluation"` and then in the script use `if (!$(this).data('exists') { return; } $.ajax(...` so that the ajax call is never made if the attribute exists

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your syntax. The click event should fire if #evaluation-panel-heading element exists in the view. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Am I sure that the Model is populating? And it is firing, but the issue is that it is firing every time. Even after the Model is populated.

Comment: Can you post the generated html for both of the situations?

Comment: In your previous question, you noted that you have multiple panels. If that's still the case here, you have a potential problem if your giving all the elements the same `id="evaluation-panel-heading"` and `id="evaluation-panel-body"` attributes

Comment: I am not, they are all unique. I have three POSTs.

Comment: I ended up just doing something like `evaluationPanelIsActive = true;` before the click event and `if(!evaluationPanelIsActive) {return;} evaluationPanelIsActive = false;` in the start of the click event

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to currently test this but I think that:

```
@if (Model.OrdersInEvaluation == null)
```

this part runs in the server side and it only renders when you first load the page. it doesn't update with your ajax call.

Maybe you can check `$("#evaluation-panel-body")` to see if it's empty ( in case that works for you)